# jQuery select just the first one

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My javascript

```
            $(".controls").click(function(event) {

                  var div = $(event.target).parents(".controls");

                  var a = $(div).find("tr .select");


            return false;
        });
```

And html

```
 <div id="grid1" class="controls">

    <a href="/projekt/create">Add</a>
    <a href="/projekt/edit">Edit</a>

</div>


<div id="grid2" class="controls">

    <a href="/uloha/create">Add</a>
    <a href="/uloha/edit">Edit</a>

    <table>
    <tr id="1"></tr>
    <tr id="2" class="select"></tr>
    <tr id="3"></tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

I'd like to select the first TR which has class `select`. 
I've tried

```
var a = $(div).find("tr:first .select");
```

or

```
var a = $(div).find("tr .select:first");
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be solved with a design re-think.. It looks like you're over-complicating things. Care to elaborate as to the whole purpose of this script?

Comment: Do you want things triggered on a click on either #grid1 or #grid2, or only if #grid1 is clicked?

Comment: I'd like to have multiple grids on one page. A grid div contains a table and a controls div where are multiple buttons.Every button has its own purpose(Add,Edit,Delete,Search). If someone clicks on a button I need to get the selected row from the propriate table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var a = $("tr.select", div).first();
```

or

```
var a = $("tr.select:first", div);
```

Since there's [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/).

To select all of this within that you use:

```
$(this, that)
```

Would something like this work?

```
$(".controls").click(function(event) {
    var a = $("tr.select:first", ".controls");
    // do stuff with a....
    return false;
});
```

This changes "two" to okay, but not 'four" when you press the button.

```
<div class="controls">
    <input type="button" value="Click the control" />
</div>
<div id="grid2" class="controls">
    <table>
        <tr id="1"><td>one</td></tr>
        <tr id="2" class="select"><td>two</td></tr>
        <tr id="3"><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr id="4" class="select"><td>four</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".controls input").click(function(event) {
        var a = $("tr.select:first", ".controls");
        $(a).text("okay");
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

(As a side note, those are not proper id names, they cannot start with a number if you want valide html)

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure what you want is this:

```
var a = $(div).find("tr.select:first");
```

In jQuery selectors, spaces separate levels in the hierarchy.

If I used the selector `"tr:first .select"` it would look in the first tr and return all children that have the select class.

If I used the selector `"tr .select:first"` it would look in every `tr` and return the first child element with the select class for each `tr`.

Comment: What is the advantage / difference of using $(div).find("tr.select:first"); vs $("tr.select:first", div); ?

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: As far as I know, they do the exact same thing.  It would be an interesting thing to profile, though.

Comment: @R. Bemrose - Thanks, that's what I thought too, just wasn't sure. It would be interesting to look into.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the index?

```
var a = $(div).find("tr.select")[0]

/* I think that's the right syntax */
```

Comment: The question is asking for the tr element with a select class.  Your solution (tr <space> .select) is finding the first child element with a select class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the first() function to do that.

```
var a = $(div).find("tr.select").first();
```